# Space available on sql server

Tags: sql-server

I have a database on my SQL Server 2008 express.

I right clicked it and i see Size is at `2.74 MB`, but Space Available shows as `0.72 MB`

What does this mean? Does this mean if i use `.72MB` more it will fill up? Can i expand this and is this an issue?

My concern is that there is some limit placed on my database but I have no idea if this is an issue or not. Someone on a forum said it should automatically grow?

[image: Here is the image]

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The space available is the difference between the space reserved and the space occupied.
If your database has 0.72 MB of free space, and the drive it's on has plenty of free space, then don't worry about it.
As long as there is sufficient space and you haven't disabled the database's ability to autogrow,then the database will grow the data file when it needs to.

Comment: Great! I have about 1TB so shouldnt be an issue then.

Comment: Where do you enable/disable auto grow in sql server 2008 for reference?

Comment: Right Click your DB->Properties->Files(on extreme left top next to General tab)

Comment: @soniccool I hope you figured out that sql 2008 express edition has a limit size of 4GB lol.
https://www.gfi.com/support/products/what-are-the-size-limitations-for-sql-express-databases#targetText=Microsoft%20SQL%20Server%202008%20Express,database%20size%20limit%20to%2010GB